# How to enable postgresql-9.6 for remote connectivity

Tags: postgresql

I have installed CentOS 7 on vmware on my Windows 8 PC. I am able to connect through F-secure from my host machine, but I am not able to connect my pgAdmin to Postgres 9.6 which I installed on my CentOS 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can ask it from postgres by logging into it and then use
**`SHOW config_file;`** like this:

```
postgres=# SHOW config_file;
               config_file
------------------------------------------
 /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
(1 row)
```

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790659/postgres-find-configuration-files-in-linux/47790660#47790660) might help you.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's work for you

```
# /var/lib/pgsql/9.x/data/pg_hba.conf
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0    md5

# vi /var/lib/pgsql/9.x/data/postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = '*'

# sudo systemctl restart postgresql-9.x.service
```

Hope this help or you can open this [link](https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/install-postgresql-on-centos-7/)

Comment: Actually the insertion of client IP address in pg_hba.conf  helped resolve the problem .