# Postgres find configuration files in linux

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.6, pg-hba.conf

I've spent lots of time to find **Postgres** configuration files like `pg_hba.conf` or `postgresql.conf` in **different distributions** of linux and also **postgres versions** itself! and I was very confused...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally, I found the global solution for it.

First, you should follow these steps:

1. Type `su - postgres` or, if that does not work, `sudo -i -u postgres` and hit <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>.
2. Type `psql` and hit <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>.
3. To find out the location of the postgres configuration file `postgresql.conf`, type:

   ```
   SHOW config_file;
   ```

   The output should be like this:

   ```
   postgres=# SHOW config_file;
                  config_file               
   -----------------------------------------
    /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
   (1 row)
   ```
4. And to find out the location of the postgres `pg_hba.conf` file, type:

   ```
   SHOW hba_file;
   ```

   There, the output should be like this:

   ```
   postgres=# SHOW hba_file;
                 hba_file               
   -------------------------------------
    /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf
   (1 row)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

If you instance is not started and you can't

```
select current_setting('hba_file')
```

or

```
select setting from pg_settings where name = 'hba_file'
```

or

```
psql -c 'show hba_file'
```

you can just find them:

```
find / -name pg_hba.conf
```