# Enable SQL debug mode in PostgreSQL 15.2

Tags: postgresql

I tried to enable full debug mode using this [Tutorial](https://cloudblue.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/44001888168-how-to-increase-postgresql-log-level-)

But in PostgreSQL 15.2 configuration file location is changed. Do you know how I can enable full debug mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres find configuration files in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790659/postgres-find-configuration-files-in-linux), [Where does PostgreSQL store configuration/conf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602450/where-does-postgresql-store-configuration-conf-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ALTER SYSTEM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html) statements:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET log_statement = 'all';
```

Depending on what you change, you have to use pg_reload_conf() to just reload the configuration or you must stop&start the database cluster.

Comment: What is the default value? Maybe `ALTER SYSTEM SET log_statement = 'info';`?

Comment: The default is ERROR, which means statements causing errors, log messages, fatal errors, or panics will be logged.